# Web software that will allow me to build a conditional wizard form?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, php, forms

I want to be able to build a dynamic online form, where user gets asked multiple questions or sets of questions and depending on their answers, they get asked other questions. Basically a tree of forms so to speak.

Is there anything like this out there?

Example:

1. Enter your first name:
2. Enter date of birth.

   if(dob) < 18 continue process A.

   if(dob) > 18 continue process B.

   Etc.

Comment: So it has to be open source and has to be in PHP, correct?

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite complex because It is not clear if you are going to actually process this forms (like receiving the answers in a database) or you just want to receive the answers in your email.

In the last case, you can use google forms, "Show questions based on answers":

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en

If you are going to process the form you need to find a Script to do this for you.

Try this terms conditional form based on answers JavaScript

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=conditional+form+based+on+answers+JavaScript

There can be some variants, like using Ajax or using Jquery, but you also need to set up a database and some server-side files to process it.